# Protect network activity while connected to VPN (AnyConnect)

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, privacy

My client's only way to connect to their server is through a VPN using AnyConnect, but I don't want all my network activity (web browsing, background apps, etc.) to show up on their network, and I certainly don't want them to access my computer.

Is there a way to protect my computer against this? Such as automatically switching my network profile to "Public", and/or allow only Remote Desktop to use the connection?

I've tried to find an answer on here, but I don't have enough rep to comment, the answers I found mostly talked about "secpol.msc" which doesn't work on Windows 10 (Windows cannot find 'secpol.msc'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.)

I just though of this, but would it work to install AnyConnect in a VM which I'd use only for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i've understood, you need to connect to a server everyonce and a while using a vpn and you don't want people to see your trafic?
If that's so, just turn off the vpn when you don't need it.

An other possibility would be that you make yourself a Virtual Machine dedicated to connect to that server. That way the vpn will only see the trafic of the virtual machine.

Cheers!

Comment: I'll go with the VPN, I think it's the best if it works, I could even let it open...

Comment: Anyconnect has a setting to not route local traffic over the VPN, but this can be overridden by the VPN administrator.  There's ways to hack around it (especially on Linux), but creating a VM in VMware just for VPN use is what I do and works well for me.  Gets around the annoying "only the VPN user can be logged in" limitation of AnyConnect as well.

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't want all my network activity (web browsing, background
>   apps, etc.) to show up on their network

Check [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/cb38ed7b-dcc5-4021-a41b-ab6a2e97eca0/always-using-the-dns-i-prefer-even-if-vpn-is-established?forum=winserverNIS&prof=required).

[image]

On some VPN connections, like SSTP VPN connection in Windows you can specify not to use the default gateway of the remote network. That way all your internet traffic does not get to the remote VPN network but directly to your normal internet gateway.

> But if you use something else, such as Cisco AnyConnect, Juniper, etc,
>   then the VPN admins have to set it up with "Split Tunneling."

See [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/100936-asa8x-split-tunnel-anyconnect-config.html).

[image]

You can use a command like this to check, how your internet traffic is being routed when connected to VPN:

```
tracert -d -w 100 www.cisco.com
```